# How to find out the name of the person that an IBAN number belongs to?

Tags: eu-citizens, banking, europe, money-transfer

If you have someone's IBAN number in another European country than the one you're in (therefore, no local branch of their bank of where you are), is there a way to find out the full name of the person that the IBAN number belongs to, so as to ensure that it is the correct person to transfer money to?

Comment: Why are you transferring money to someone _you don't know_ ? That sounds very suspicious.

Comment: What makes you think it might not be the right person? You can possibly use a checker such as https://www.moneymover.com/about/faqs/what-iban/ to confirm the bank name and address, and the account number, but not the actual account name details

Comment: for example, if they give the IBAN number alone, and not info about themselves. Names can be really complex for some cultures, and a mismatch, despite being semi-aware of someone's *documented* identity, is more common than you think (and will even become irrelevant as the crypto economy overtakes fiat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. That would be a big breach of all kinds of privacy laws.

What you can do is give the name of the account holder when you transfer the money.

Then the bank *should* reject it when you put in "John Doe" but the account is registered to "Regina Miller".

But they will never *give* you the data.

<sup>(Just for the record, IBAN accounts are not anonymous. If the police comes knocking with a warrant, the will get the name and all data easily. But a private person has no right to get this data from the bank.)</sup>

Comment: Not all banks check foreign account details routinely, some may do on request.

Comment: While this is true for IBAN in EU, there are a fair amount of countries which do have public or semi-public name lookup feature for bank and mobile accounts.One example is Nigeria

Comment: So where are these public name lookups?

Answer (score 1):

In Portugal, if you make a cash deposit in certain Millennium bcp automatic teller machines, when you insert the IBAN it will show the account holder's name for confirmation purposes. It may happen with other banks, I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting, do you know if it only works with other Millennium customers? Customers from other Portuguese banks? Is there a system to share this data Europe-wide?